# How to get text to display over images in a table?

Tags: html, css, image, text

I'm trying to get the text to display over each individual image, I can't figure out why it's not displaying at all. From what I can tell I don't have the text hidden or anything, it's just not displaying on top of the corrisponding images.

I'm very new to html/css so i'm proberly missing someting quite obvious.

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="index">
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="C:\Users\44074\Desktop\Learnnig\Website\Art\Care-Guide.jpg">
        Care guides
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="C:\Users\44074\Desktop\Learnnig\Website\Art\Prop.jpg">
        Propagation
    </td> 
    <td> 
        <img src="C:\Users\44074\Desktop\Learnnig\Website\Art\Trouble.jpg">
        Troubleshooting
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="C:\Users\44074\Desktop\Learnnig\Website\Art\Easy.jpg">
        Easy plants
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="C:\Users\44074\Desktop\Learnnig\Website\Art\Pilea.jpg">
        Pilea
    </td> 
    <td>
        <img src="C:\Users\44074\Desktop\Learnnig\Website\Art\Pets.jpg">
        Pets & plants
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

table.index{
table-layout: fixed;
border-spacing: 25px 35px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #575151;
padding-left: 180px;
padding-right: 180px;
}

table.index td {
height: 220px;
width: 360px;
min-width: 200px;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #575151;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}

table.index td img {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

div.index {
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your text in an HTML element for example p tag: `<p>Easy plants</p>`

Give the p element a relative position: `position: relative;`

This will position it over the absolutely positioned image.
If you happen to change the order of the images and the text elements later, you should give the text elements a higher z-index value than the images.